# How can I delete a specific character from each string in an array in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a string in an array called imgss . At this time, I want to subtract only the number from the string and put it in the answer variable. So imgss copied and then splice was written, but it does not work as there may be multiple numbers. How do I fix my code?

this is my code

```
    const imgss = ["ecdysisInfo 1", "growthLength 2", "wormHeadSize 1234"]


    const image = [...imgss]

    image.splice(0, 2);

    expected answer 

    const answer = ["ecdysisInfo", "growthLength", "wormHeadSize"]
```

Comment: Try `const expected = imgss.map(item => item.split(' ')[0]);` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) each item with space

```js
const imgss = ["ecdysisInfo 1", "growthLength 2", "wormHeadSize 1234"]

const image = imgss.map((item) => item.split(' ')[0]);

console.log(image)
```

OR you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and regex to remove all numbers and spaces

```js
const imgss = ["ecdysisInfo 1", "growthLength 2", "wormHeadSize 1234"]

const result = imgss.map((item) => item.replace(/[0-9 ]/g, ''));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did :

```js
const imgss = ["ecdysisInfo 1", "growthLength 2", "wormHeadSize 1234"]
    const answer = imgss.map(str=> str.replace(' ','').split('').filter(item=>!item.match(/[0-9]/i)).join(''));
    console.log(answer)
```